# How to retry particular piece of code in try block if any exceptions are happening?

Tags: java, try-catch

I need to parse my HTML table coming from an URL using JSOUP and everything is working fine as of now. Now I want to add a retry mechanism if I see any exception. Below is my code -

```
public void collectMetrics() {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("some_url");
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 9000);
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mappings.entrySet()) {
            calculateDiskFree(doc, entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
        }
        // if it comes here, then it means everything is done successfully 
        // so no retry has to happen now
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If there are any exceptions happening in the catch block, I would like to retry executing everything I have in my try block for `n` number of times. Is it possible to do?

Comment: wrap it all in a while loop and set some flags in your catches

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put it in a loop.

```
boolean successful = false;
while (!successful) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("some_url");
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 9000);
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mappings.entrySet()) {
            calculateDiskFree(doc, entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
        }
        successful = true;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but you might then want to think about what happens if it just keeps failing.
If you only want to retry some specific number of times you can use a `for` loop.

```
for (int retries = 0; retries < 3; ++retries) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("some_url");
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 9000);
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mappings.entrySet()) {
            calculateDiskFree(doc, entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
        }
        break;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Provides an infinite loop solution and a  safer try-limit solution

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the try block in an infinite loop and add `return;` after your work code:

```
public void collectMetrics() {
    for (;;) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("some_url");
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 9000);
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mappings.entrySet()) {
                calculateDiskFree(doc, entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
            }
            return;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to limit the number of tries (recommended), fill out the for loop, ie instead of `for (;;)`, use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {  // try max 10 times
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a while statement around the try catch statement then set up something to tell the while loop to stop repeating.